# ASP.NET Core google authentication redirects to email confirmation

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, razor-pages

I added google authentication to my ASP.NET Core razor pages website.
I followed the instructions and it worked well. Still, after the successful authentication, I was  redirected to a page called `ExternalLogin` in which I was asked to put my email address for confirmation with the message:

> "You've successfully authenticated with Google. Please enter an email
> address for this site below and click the Register button to finish
> logging in."

I don't think I ever saw such behavior on any website. How do I change it to skip the confirmation? Why did they choose it to be the default? I don't see when confirmation would be necessary since the authentication succeeds only if the user is logged in.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly likely you followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-authentication-providers .

You could set the `options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false` here to skip email confirmation or just delete this option.

[image]

Comment: It didn't help.
Also I do want to ask to confirm account in case of regular authentication.